# how to get current Mainpage instance in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get the current window on my Windows Phone Application.

In WPF i was doing like this:

MainWindow m = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow

Is there something equivalent in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
```

Comment: MainPage currentPage = (MainPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;